# How to upload a theme in drupal.org?

Tags: drupal, themes

How can i upload a theme on Drupal.org?
so i register to the site, and next?

Comment: I'd love to help you, but I don't quite get your question! Please edit it or something to be a little more clearer - do you want to submit your theme to drupal so anybody can download it from Drupal.org? At least, if you edit it, someone can help. At the minute it looks like you spent 10 seconds on it and it's in your own wierd langauge :P

Comment: Yes, i wants that anyone can download my theme from drupal.org.Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean to insult your langauge or anything! Do you mind me asking a genuine question though? Why don't you use Google Translate or something when using forums (posting)?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if I was right in my comment and you are a developer wanting **contribute** your theme to drupal.org, you need to make sure your themes comply with [Drupal Coding Standards](http://drupal.org/coding-standards) and you need to be prepared to license them under [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html), firstly.

After, when your ready, you need to apply for a CVS account. It will have to be reviewed and approved, but once it is you'll be able to **Add your theme to Drupal.org**!

Please visit http://drupal.org/contribute/themes *> How to add your theme to Drupal.org*, for more information.

Hope That Helps

Andy

PS I've interpreted your message this time, but just remember to take more care, effort and time in the future!

Comment: Note that when you wait until the 17th or so, you will be able to use the much improved, git-backed workflow. Then you will be able to upload the theme to a somewhat hidden sandbox project, which can be reviewed and once ready, be promoted to a full public project. A CVS application can take weeks and month to complete because of the limited manpower.

Comment: I arrive in this page: http://drupal.org/cvs-application, but it say me that i haven't accept the GPl license, where can i accept it?

Comment: Sorry alex, I haven't got a drupal account so it's beyond my help now really! But a few pointers. 1) It would be nice to have some feedback as to weather we gave you the right information! 2) Google's you friend, not only does it allow you to translate your own lanauge to english for cases like this, so all of us get understood properly first time. But if you've got a couple of minutes, you can find the answer to most things! I didn't know what I told you before I googled it, but it took 10 seconds to find out, so I'm sure your second question will yield helpful results on Google too!

Comment: I search 3 hours in google, the information is correct, but i can't find the right documentation step by step, i think i wait the 17th when all change to git. Thankyou